# Resize File Please

Tags: java, android, resize

I've tried numerous forms but I'm not getting the size of my photos at all, they're coming out with more than 3mb and I need them to upload numerous pictures via FTP. Follow code for someone could demonstrate a functional gradient

```
    File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Generating the image - method started");

    // New Image 
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = os_id+ "_"+ txtCheckList_id.getText().toString() + "_" + txtCheckListItens_id.getText().toString() + "_1A_"  + timeStamp;
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "GRP");

    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Storage directory set");
    if (!storageDirectory.exists()) storageDirectory.mkdir();
    File image = new File(storageDirectory, imageFileName + ".png");

    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("File name and path set");
   mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
 return image;

}
```

Comment: It is not clear, what you want? size of the file, upload it to FTP?

Comment: I want size file.

Comment: The answer provide by @ArsalImam does exactly that...it gives you the file size. :: How you proceed is up to you.--- But, I assume you want much more. I assume you want someone to show you how to reduce the size of the image file in order to reduce the payload when you upload the file?

Comment: That! How to implement his suggestion in code

Comment: The code you have posted is nowhere near what you need to do what you want. There are a lot of tutorials on the web to look at. But, the logic would be: locate image you wish to upload, reduce image size (you can use `compress()` method) then upload the image as a stream...no need to temporarily save the image to disk...unless you want to for the future.

Comment: I understand, the license is showing and I have to show an example how I would get an image for KB with an "image" variable that I got in SDCARD as coded above.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `file.length()` to get the size of the file, please check the mentioned example,

```
int file_size = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()/1024));
```

Comment: I inserted in the code this function and now how should I proceed